# Integer sequence $(u_n)$ satisfying $(an+b)u_{n+1}=(cn+d)u_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

The integer-valued sequence $u_n=\binom{2n}{n}$ satisfies the recurrence relation $(n+1)u_{n+1}=2(2n+1)u_n$.

My question : for which values $a,b,c,d\in{\mathbb Z}$ is there a sequence
$(u_n)$ (not eventually constant) satisfying the recurrence relation $(an+b)u_{n+1}=(cn+d)u_n$ ?

My thoughts : Legendre's formula shows that $\nu_p(n!) \leq \frac{n}{p-1}$ for large $n$ when $p$ is prime, so this shows that if $a=0$ and $c=1$, $b$ cannot have  an odd prime divisor, so $b$ must be a power of $2$. Not sure how the general case can be handled.

Comment: For your specific case of $ a = 0, c = 1$, the telescoping product gives $ u_{n+1} = u_1 \prod \frac{n+d}{b} $. If $b > 1$, then for any prime $ p \mid b$, $v_p ( (n+d)! ) \leq \frac{ n+d } { p - 1 }  < n$ for large enough $n$, so we must have $ b = 1$, which gives $ u_{n+1} = u_1 \prod (n+d)$.

Comment: In fact, for $ a = 0 $, I believe that similarly $ b \mid \gcd (c, d)$ in order for there to be solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If you have
$$(a\,n+b)\,u_{n+1}=(c\,n+d)\,u_n$$ the general term is given in terms of Pochhammer symbols
$$u_n=u_0\,\frac db\,\left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^{n-1}\, \frac{  \left(\frac{c+d}{c}\right)_{n-1}}{
   \left(\frac{a+b}{a}\right)_{n-1}}$$ which, for large values of $n$, is
$$u_n \sim u_0\,\frac db\,\,\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{a+b}{a}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{c+d}{c}\right)}\,\left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^{n-1}\,(n-1)^{\left(\frac{d}{c}-\frac{b}{a}\right)}$$
If you want a better approximation, muliply the above by
$$\exp{\left(\frac{(a d-b c) (ac+ad +b c)}{2 a^2 c^2 (n-1)} \right) }$$

Comment: The upshot of this is that we must have $\frac{d}{c}-\frac{b}{a}\geq 0$ (and the equality case is easy). Where do you get the Pochhammer symbol estimate from ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy. $$\log \left((k)_n\right)=n (\log (n)-1)+\left(\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (n)+\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{2
   \pi }}{\Gamma (k)}\right)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$